# Delegates and Events in Interface?

Tags: .net

Can we implement delegates and events in Interface?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify an event in an interface, but you can't declare a delegate (or any other type) - at least not in C#. For instance:

```
// Valid
public delegate void BarHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);        
public interface IFoo
{
    event BarHandler Bar;
}

// Invalid
public interface IFoo
{
    delegate void BarHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);        
    event BarHandler Bar;
}
```

Comment: Why a delegate can't be declared in an interface? What logic of language designers is in it?

Comment: @SukhdevZala: Well you can't declare *any* type within an interface in C#. The only reason to do so would be to qualify the type name, basically... it wouldn't be part of what a type implementing the interface would provide.